Can I use SQL to input multiple date ranges in one record?
I would like to write code to input multiple date ranges for one person. For example, I am trying to create a table to keep track of employee vacation time.
Let's say:

Jeff takes off 2/13-2/19 and 12/5-12/7
Molly takes off 5/3
Jane takes off 1/5-1/10 and 7/19-8/24 and 11/14-11/23

I would like to input all these ranges for each person and query based on date. I would like to know all the employees who took time off on 7/20, for example.
I wrote this so far but I am stumped on the date portion. Most resources online show you how to store one date per record.
CREATE TABLE vacayTracker
(
    employeeID INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    Email VARCHAR(100),
    vacationDays DATE, 
    PRIMARY KEY (employeeID)
)


Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, some products have their own, non-standard formats.)

You have to break your structure into multiple tables and join them with keys. In Relational database terminology, this is called normalization.
For example: Your Employee table has the EmployeeID as the primary key and has exactly one row (record) for each employee.
Your VacationTracker table has multiple rows for each employee and its EmployeeID column is a foreign key that points to the Employee.EmployeeID primary key. You insert multiple rows into the VacationTracker table for each date range.
Employee
EmployeeID int PRIMARY  KEY
EmployeeName varchar(100)

VacationTracker
EmployeeID int FOREIGN KEY (Employee.EmployeeID)
StartDate DateTime
EndDate DateTime

You can then query the table using an SQL query like:
SELECT E.EmployeeID, E.EmployeeName, V.StartDate, V.EndDate
FROM Employee E INNER JOIN VacationTracker V ON E.EmployeeID = V.EmployeeID
WHERE @InputDate BETWEEN V.StartDate and V.EndDate

Where @InputDate contains the date you wish to check.

You need to normalize this out into separate tables. The dates should be in two separate columns of start and end, a separate row for each vacation.
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    EmployeeID INT NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE EmployeeVacation (
    EmployeeID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Employee (EmployeeId),
    VacationStart DATE NOT NULL,
    VacationEnd DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID, VacationStart, VacationEnd),
    CHECK (VacationStart < VacationEnd)
);

To query this you could use joins
SELECT e.*
FROM Employee e
JOIN EmployeeVacation ev ON ev.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
WHERE ev.VacationStart <= '20240720'
  AND ev.VacationEnd >= '20240720';


This may be DB specific.  In MySql dates go by 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

Still alowed but not recommended https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html OP did not specify the DBMS.

ISO/ANSI SQL date literal: DATE'2024-07-20'

True but that doesn't work in SQL Server for example, and OP did not specify the DBMS as I said. If  they do then I will correct to the recommended way for that system.
